# JPA SELECT from a list

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am not seem to be able to run this simple query. I have a list of ids and I want to retrieve all the rows with this id from db.

```
 List<String> uniqueIds is my list.
```

I have tried `String q = "SELECT item FROM Tenant item WHERE item.id IN (:"+uniqueIds+")";`

I have also tried this without : and (). Non of them worked. What am I doing wrong. I also tried for (String uniqueId : uniqueIds) {
        in += uniqueId + ",";
    }

and used "in" as well!

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're supposed to bind parameters to a query. Parameters are anonymous (`?`) or named (`:parameterName`):

```
TypedQuery<Tenant> query = 
    em.createQuery("select item from Tenant item where item.id in :ids", Tenant.class);
query.setParameter("ids", uniqueIds);
List<Tenant> result = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Let me try that tomorrow. I ll get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: This should have more upvotes. Please notice that you cannot use anonymous parameters when you want to use LISTS. This is deprecated and will cause an exception. Always use named parameters.